# Optional Modal message selenium Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, popup, robotframework

How do I handle an optional modal message that pops up on the screen while using Selenium Robot Framework. For example Insufficient balance alert. I cannot see the current balance on the account, that is retrieved from back end. Depending on the balance the pop up may or maynot show up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code may solve your problem:

```
try: 
   modal = browser.switch_to.alert
   modal.accept()
except:
   # YOUR NORMAL CODE IF MODAL IS NOT GENERATED
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I had used your idea just TRY/EXCEPT feature is available from Robot framework 5.0
So I did the following;

TRY
      click Button   Xpath://
EXCEPT       no previous tickets
       click Button    xpath://
END